# Is it possible to add a query string to a request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a controller that needs to 
1) receive a request and process it 
2) invoke a model based on the request params
3) send the request to an api wrapper 
4) receive the output of that api call and return to the user

The problem is that the controller takes its parameters in the format `controller/:param1/:param2` whereas the model uses the request.query_string method to extract everything after the `?`in the request url. Since the `request.query_string` method returns blank for requests to my controller, I need to add a query string to the request before sending it on to the model. Does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

Comment: wouldn't be the better solution to write a rack middleware?

Answer (score 1):

When redirecting from the first controller to the second one, you can add query strings to the url.

For example:

```rb
redirect_to some_path(:foo => 1, :bar => 2, ...)
```

Then `request.query_string` in the second controller would be:

```rb
"foo=1&bar=2"
```

Comment: Hi, that would work fine but the controller needs to retain control of the execution flow. I've edited my question to make things a little clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @ronan_mac In most cases, it is not a good idea to access `request.query_string` in models. What do you mean by "invoke a model"? Do you call an instance method on a record? Or a class method of a model? In either case, you can pass necessary information as the arguments of that method call.

Comment: I'm working on a project which uses [Umlaut](https://github.com/team-umlaut/umlaut/) a service aggregator for library front ends. The model in this case is a umlaut specific Request model which creates an OpenUrl context object from an OpenUrl contained within the query string. Of course I can edit things in the model's own code to enable passing as you say, but this would mix my own application logic in with the umlaut code. Experience tells me that it is better to keep local logic separate  from the logic of imported code.